# Showing that for $S^1 \subset \mathbb C$, the induced homomorphism of $f_n = z^n$ corresponds to multiplying by n

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm just starting to learn algebraic topology and was doing some simple exercises.

Let $S^1 \subset \mathbb C $ be the circle as a subset of the complex numbers (with $\pi(S^1, 1_\mathbb C) \approx \mathbb Z $), and define $f_n: S^1 \to S^1$ where $f_n(z)=z^n$. I know that $(f_n)_*$ corresponds to multiplication by n, but I don't know how to show it.

I'm not sure what's the best way to go about it. Perhaps by defining a function $g_n:S^1 \to S^1, g_n(z)=zn$ and showing that $(g_n)_* \equiv (f_n)_*$ or showing that $f_n$ and $g_n$ are homotopic to each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition of $g_n$ doesn't seem right. If $z\in S^1$, i.e., $|z|=1$, then $nz\notin S^1$.

To show that $(f_n)_*=\bullet \cdot n$, take your favorite generator $[\lambda]$ of $\pi_1(S^1)\cong \Bbb Z$. So $\lambda$ is a path that maps to $1$ in the fundamendal group. Then $(f_n)_*$ is determined by it's value on $[\lambda]$. But $$(f_n)_*([\lambda])=[f_n\circ \lambda].$$ So you should show that $[f_n\circ \lambda]$ is $n$  in $\pi_1(S^1)\cong \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Oh I get it now. Thanks!